# GTL Json data looping

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, loop, gtl

I have a GTL code that loops through my JSON code. In the JSON string i have several order data but in each array there is the same adress information like so:

```
[{
"name":"This is a name",
"sku":"8547",
"street":"Test street",
"housenumber":"23",
"postalcode":"2595AK",
"city":"Den Haag",
"landname":"Nederland"
},
{
"name":"This is another name",
"sku":"6343",
"street":"Test street",
"housenumber":"23",
"postalcode":"2595AK",
"city":"Den Haag",
"landname":"Nederland"
},
{
"name":"Something",
"sku":"0459",
"street":"Test street",
"housenumber":"23",
"postalcode":"2595AK",
"city":"Den Haag",
"landname":"Nederland"
}]
```

So the name and the sku's are different but the address details are the same. Is there a way or a workaround to print out one time the address details if the address is everywhere the same? Ofcourse if there are three different address details i have to show all three of them. Hope it's a bit clear what i have to achieve.

Thanks a lot,
Martijn

Comment: I was facing similar issue, but GTL has some limitations e.g. finding an index from an array. Checkout this video it may help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfCvc0w3Fbk